# NetBeans Build Failed - JasperException

Tags: web, netbeans, glassfish

I moved my web project to another directory. I reopened it through NetBeans from the new directory. Running it resulted in the following error:

`Created dir: C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\projectSourceCode\arthurProj\build\generated\src
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6149: The -uriroot option must specify a pre-existing directory
C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\projectSourceCode\arthurProj\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)`

Should I change something in the `build-impl.xml` file before moving the project folder? I tried "clean and build" but the same error appears. How do I "specify a pre-existing directory"?

The `build-impl.xml` file: http://pastebin.com/PFv2aAjh

Answer (score 0):

Goto your project folder and delete `build` and `dist` folders manually.

For example, if your project path like this `C:\WebProject\build\` and `C:\WebProject\dist`, so delete these 2 folders. Now try `clean and bulid` project, this will create a fresh `build and dist` directories.